# How to consume OData services from local sandbox system in sapui5 application in webide?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sandbox

I am trying to access OData services which is on local sandbox system in sapui5 application in WEBIDE and I am able to READ data and display in ui5 app but not

able to create POST request, getting "500 Internal Server".

Here I am not using destinations in hana cockpit.

Please guide me.

Can we post the data to local service which is on local server?

Thanks.

Comment: fix the server error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an configuration file in the config master folder of your local web IDE